# Females on Christianity.SE

Tags: discussion, users

I have this feeling that this site is male dominated which is normal but I think women patronage is too low if I'm right. First of all I'll want to know the ladies currently using this site. Let's acknowledge them. And if anyone agrees with me, let's put up something that attracts the ladies to also balance the site with their contributions. I'm sure this will help so much.

Though I haven't any idea yet how we can feminine-spice up the main site and meta, I think we should start thinking about that. What do you say?

Comment: I don't really see that many girls on StackExchange sites in general.  I don't think this one is too different from the others...

Comment: @Mason in other words, there's nothing we can do, isn't it?

Comment: If you want women to use this site, try talking to women you know who are interested in Christian doctrine and inviting them to come here.

Comment: @Mason Yes I have been trying that already. But rather got a guy, Edem. The women did not respond

Comment: @Mason in fact here, they are rather the most 'spiritual'.

Comment: We put out [a call for female blog contributors](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/955/914), but got no response.

Comment: It is a problem. No idea what to do about it, though. [Diverstiy does matter](http://timothy.green.name/links/the-value-of-diversity/).

Comment: I'm not sure it's appropriate to ask the women to identify themselves. Anyone who wants to disclose their gender publicly can do so on their profile. Otherwise, why is it anyone's business?

Comment: @Flimzy. It does matter, though. **Diversity is important in and of itself.**

Comment: @TRiG: I wasn't arguing against the importance of diversity; only against the appropriateness of asking any women to identify themselves. Should we ask all minorities to identify themselves?

Comment: SE's growth started based on 3 IT related sites, the biggest of which was for programmers...and the seed users for most of our sites come from there. IT's male dominance has pretty much become SE's male dominance, but it should lessen as the network diversifies.

Comment: Additionally, it's much much safer, for unfortunate reasons, to identify oneself as clearly male on many public websites. Trying to call out for female users might actually do nothing but reinforce that line of thought... -- Ben "Brock Manly" Brocka

Answer (score 8):

It's not just C.SE that has this problem. It's not even just the SE network that has this problem. It's the whole Internet.

The anonymous nature of the Internet has made it easy for people to harass women--they see an obvious feminine username on a chat room/forum/etc and make comments directed at the user, knowing full well that there (usually) isn't any way for the user to retaliate. No need to go into details here, we all know what I'm talking about.

Obviously, someone who has been/expects to be treated like this will (a) not touch the Internet, or (b) Not make her gender clear.

Couple this with the fact that most SE site users are primarily programmers (and IT is a male-dominated field), and you sort of get an idea why we don't see many women on the network.

---

The suggestion of having them identify themselves will be detrimental--it sounds discriminating and will just make the ladies more wary of the Net.

---

I don't know how to fix this--looking at the reasons behind this, I can't cook up anything.

Wikipedia has [had](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/31/business/media/31link.html?_r=1) [a similar](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2012/04/27/nine-out-of-ten-wikipedians-continue-to-be-men/) [problem](http://suegardner.org/2011/02/19/nine-reasons-why-women-dont-edit-wikipedia-in-their-own-words/), and they [did](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2012/03/28/advocate-for-women-in-open-source-to-keynote-2012-wikimania/) [put effort](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2012/03/30/ada-initiatives-quest-to-bring-women-to-open-source/) [into correcting](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2012/03/23/wikiwomens-history-month-encourages-women-to-edit-wikipedia/) [this](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2012/03/27/wiki-women-joining-indic-languages/). They were only partially successful, I remember seeing some reports on it (and hearing about it internally), but nothing big. Unfortunate, really--but you can research their efforts and try something along those lines; learn from their mistakes.

If you do manage to cook up something tangible, be sure to let the rest of us on SE know--I think this is applicable network-wide.